# selecting checkbox value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have some 5 static checkboxes in my html page.
And i want to get the values of a selected checkbox when i click on submit button.

Below is my code snippet,please correct me where am wrong.

for i in 101..105

```
  if (params[":Prod"+i] == 'selected')
    @userid=session[:userid].to_i
    @prodid="Prod"+i.to_i
    @prodname=params[":ProdName"+i].to_s
    @price=params[":Price"+i].to_i
    @qty=params[":qty"+i].to_i
    @Products=Product.create :UserId =>@userid, :ProductId =>@prodid, :ProductName     =>@prodname, :Price =>@price,:Quantity =>@qty

    if @Products.save
      redirect_to viewcart_path
    else
      render products_path
   end

  end
```

Note:My checkboxes id's are Prod101,Prod102,Prod103,Prod104 and Prod105 which i have defined static in my html page.

Comment: The colons in your param keys don't look right.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic hash keys similar to what you're trying, but the syntax is a little off.  Use:

```
params[:"Prod#{i}"]
```

or

```
params["Prod#{i}".to_sym]
```

Note that the value is not `"selected"` unless you've set that yourself in the view.  Depending on whether or not you're using helpers to create the checkboxes, and which helpers/gems you might be using, the values can vary.  It's likely you'll get "1" for checked boxes if you haven't overridden it.  You might get "0" for unchecked boxes, but by default browsers don't send *anything* for unchecked boxes, so the param might not be there at all.  Some of the form helpers trick the browser into sending "0" by using hidden form fields.  Also note that `"0"` is a true value in Ruby, so you should explicitly check for `"1"` or whatever checked value you've provided in the form.  Check your logs and see what the form submits to be sure.